# Showing a class is a set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

The problem is to determine that a given class is or is not a set only using the basic axioms of modern set theory and some examples of classes that are or are not sets. The class in question is $$\mathfrak{A} = \{\mathcal{P}(X) | X \subseteq A \},$$ where $A$ is an arbitrary set. Here is my attempt at the problem:

First prove a lemma,

---

**Lemma:**
Let $A$ be a set. Then $$\bigcup_{X \subseteq A} \mathcal{P}(X) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\bigcup_{X \subseteq A} X)$$
(pf):
Let $$S \in \bigcup_{X \subseteq A} \mathcal{P}(X)$$ $\Rightarrow$ $S \subseteq X$ for at least one $X \subseteq A$

$\Rightarrow$ $S \subseteq \bigcup_{X \subseteq A} X$

$\Rightarrow$ $S \in \mathcal{P}(\bigcup_{X \subseteq A} X)$

$\therefore \bigcup_{X \subseteq A} \mathcal{P}(X) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\bigcup_{X \subseteq A} X)$

---

Now by the unionset axiom $$\bigcup \mathfrak{A} = \bigcup \mathcal{P}(X) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\bigcup X) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A).$$

Then by a previous exercise $\bigcup \mathfrak{A} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A) \Leftrightarrow \bigcup \mathfrak{A}$ is a set as $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is a set. Therefore, $\mathfrak{A}$ is a set as $\bigcup \mathfrak{A}$ is a set.

Quod Erat Demonstratum?

Comment: I know the axiom "If $A$ is a set then $\bigcup A$ is a set". You donÄt use this axiom, but its converse ... (Also it should be the the gerundivum in the latin phrase *Quod erat demonstrandum* ;)

Comment: Ah I see, I was wondering if that would be a problem. I wasn't sure if axioms were something like definitions. That is, definitions are "secretly" if-and-only-if statements. So then I should be using that to _disprove_ a class is a set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easiest to use the replacement schema. $\varphi(a,b)$ being $b=\mathcal P(a)$.

Your proof is somewhat unclear. The lemma is a good start, but you need to argue now that $\frak A$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P(P(}A))$.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. So we can take an arbitrary $\mathcal{P}(X) \in \mathfrak{A}$ and show that $\mathcal{P}(X) \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$ which would follow via application of the Lemma. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to simply define $\mathfrak U$ as a subset of $\mathscr P\mathscr P A$.